# Package pgf Error: No shape named `chart -1-2' is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, diagrams

I am trying to make a flowchart in Latex, but I keep getting this error;
"Package pgf Error: No shape named `chart -1-2' is known"

I looked up similar questions, but none use `matrix`.
Does anyone have an idea where my problem is?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,shapes}
%define styles for nodes
\tikzset{ treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, anchor=center, text width=5em, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20, inner sep=1ex}, decision/.style = {treenode, diamond, inner sep=0pt}, root/.style ={treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30}, env/.style = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize}, finish/.style   = {root, bottom color=green!40}, dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}}
%create useful shortcuts
\newcommand{\yes}{edge node [above] {yes}}
\newcommand{\no}{edge  node [left]  {no}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (chart)
[
      matrix of nodes,
      column sep      = 3em,
      row sep         = 5ex,
      column 1/.style = {nodes={treenode}},
      column 2/.style = {nodes={treenode}}
    ]
{
       & |[root]| Collect data \\
       &  Preliminary checks on data quality  \\
       &  Diagnostics for relationships and strong interactions  \\
Remedial measures &     \\
       & | [decision]| Are remedial measures needed?  \\
       & Determine several potential useful subsets of explanatory variables; include known essential variables  \\
       & Investigate curvature and interaction effects more fully \\
Remedial measures & Study residuals and other diagnostics \\
      & | [decision]| Remedial measures needed?  \\
      & Select tentative model \\
      & | [ decision]| Validity checks?  \\
      & | [finish]| Final regression model  \\
};
\draw(chart -1-2) edge (chart -2-2)
\draw(chart -4-1.west) -- ++(-1,0) node[midway,above]{yes} |- (chart -3-2.west)
\draw(chart - 9 - 2.west) --++(-1,0) node[midway,above]{yes} |- (chart -7 -2.west)
\draw(chart -11 -2.west) --++(-2,0) node [midway,above] {no} |- (chart -1 -2.west)
\draw(chart -5 -2 ) \no (chart -6-2)
\draw(chart -9-2) \no (chart -10-2)
\draw(chart -11-2) \yes (chart -12- 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: don't sent only snippets, create a small, but full document. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: I added the whole code. Cant seem to get the picture in it.

Comment: No time to check more, but the name of the matrix is `chart`, so the nodes are `chart-1-1` etc (no spaces!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Added are braces on the right side of flowchart.

Your flowchart can be simple drawn by use of `chains` library. At least code is much shorter, clear and less prone to errors. For example, in your MWE are beside errors in writing coordinates name and terminating of lines (corrected in the other answer) missed many arrows between nodes and fact, that the flowchart is much higher than page. That flowchart can be fit, in MWE below two measures have been taken: increase text area size and used wider nodes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[showframe,  % in real document remove this option
            margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shadows, shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
BC/.style = {
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=1mm},
        ultra thick,
        pen colour={#1}
        },
}

\begin{document}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5mm and 8mm,
      start chain = A going below,
%
        arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
      base/.style = {draw, rounded corners,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
                     text width=68mm, minimum height=8mm,
                     align=center, drop shadow,
                     on chain=A},
     start/.style = {base, bottom color=red!20, text width=34mm},    
      stop/.style = {base, ellipse, text width=34mm,
                     bottom color=green!40},    
   process/.style = {base, fill=orange!30},                 
%        io/.style = {base, trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
%                     trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
%                     fill=blue!30},
  decision/.style = {base, bottom color=cyan!50, diamond, aspect=2, text width=34mm},
       lbl/.style = {label=above left:#1, font=\footnotesize}
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={join=by arr}]
\node [start]       {Collect data};             % <-- A-1
\node [process]     {Preliminary checks on data quality};
\node [process]     {Diagnostics for relationships and strong interactions Remedial measures};
\node [decision]    {Are remedial measures needed?};
\node [process]     {Determine several potential useful subsets
                     of explanatory variables; include known essential variables};
\node [process]     {Investigate curvature and interaction effects more fully  
                     Remedial measures};
\node [process]     {Study residuals and other diagnostics};
\node [decision]    {Remedial measures needed?};
\node [process]     {Select tentative model};
\node [decision]    {Validity checks?};
\node [stop]        {Final regression model};                     % <-- A-11   
    \end{scope}
% nodes in the left branch
\node [process, text width=32mm, 
       left=of $(A-3.west)!0.5!(A-3.west |- A-4)$] {Remedial measures needed?};
\node [process, text width=32mm, left=of A-7]      {Remedial measures};
% connection not considered in "join" macro
\coordinate[left=of A-12] (aux);
\draw[arr]  (A-10.west) node[lbl=No] {} -| (aux) |- (A-2);
\draw[arr]  (A-12) |- (A-3);
\draw[arr]  (A-4.west) node[lbl=Yes] {} -| (A-12);
%
\draw[arr]  (A-13) |- (A-6);
\draw[arr]  (A-8.west) node[lbl=Yes] {} -| (A-13);
% path edge quotes in main branch
\path   (A-4) to ["No"] (A-5.north)
        (A-8) to ["No"] (A-9.north)
        (A-10) to ["Yes"] (A-11.north);% braces
    \begin{scope}[nodes={text width=24mm, align=left, right=3mm}]
\coordinate (aux) at (A-1.north -| A-2.east);
\draw[BC=red]   (aux) -- 
                    node {some text in two rows} (A-4.south -| aux);
\draw[BC=red]   (aux |- A-5.north) -- 
                    node {some text longer test in three rows} (A-5.south -| aux);
\draw[BC=red]   (aux |- A-6.north) --
                    node {some text in two rows} (A-9.south -| aux);
\draw[BC=red]   (aux |- A-10.north) --
                    node {some text in two rows} (A-10.south -| aux);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You! this came out better.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the spaces that you added in the node names. Please take care of these, because `chart -1-2` is different from `chart-1-2`!

Also, each TikZ command should end with a semicolon.

Try this, but you still need to scale everything and check the connections between the nodes, I think:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,shapes}
%define styles for nodes
\tikzset{ treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, anchor=center, text width=5em, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20, inner sep=1ex}, decision/.style = {treenode, diamond, inner sep=0pt}, root/.style = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30}, env/.style = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize}, finish/.style = {root, bottom color=green!40}, dummy/.style = {circle,draw}}
%create useful shortcuts
\newcommand{\yes}{edge node [above] {yes}}
\newcommand{\no}{edge node [left] {no}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (chart)
[
      matrix of nodes,
      column sep      = 3em,
      row sep         = 5ex,
      column 1/.style = {nodes={treenode}},
      column 2/.style = {nodes={treenode}}
    ]
{
       & |[root]| Collect data \\
       &  Preliminary checks on data quality  \\
       &  Diagnostics for relationships and strong interactions  \\
Remedial measures &     \\
       & |[decision]| Are remedial measures needed?  \\
       & Determine several potential useful subsets of explanatory variables; include known essential variables  \\
       & Investigate curvature and interaction effects more fully \\
Remedial measures & Study residuals and other diagnostics \\
      & |[decision]| Remedial measures needed?  \\
      & Select tentative model \\
      & |[decision]| Validity checks?  \\
      & |[finish]| Final regression model  \\
};
\draw(chart-1-2) edge (chart-2-2);
\draw(chart-4-1.west) -- ++(-1,0) node[midway,above]{yes} |- (chart-3-2.west);
\draw(chart-9-2.west) --++(-1,0) node[midway,above]{yes} |- (chart-7-2.west);
\draw(chart-11-2.west) --++(-2,0) node [midway,above] {no} |- (chart-1-2.west);
\draw(chart-5-2) \no (chart-6-2);
\draw(chart-9-2) \no (chart-10-2);
\draw(chart-11-2) \yes (chart-12-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I posted a preliminary version of the code obviously. I primarily wanted to point out the problem with the spaces in node names though.